# Find the sum of Amount in dynamic web-table when click on respective checkbox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I have column name as Id ,Name, Descriptions and Amount and checkbox against each row. If I check checkbox then the respective amount should get sum up and total value should display. Also there is Received-Amount text-box above the web-table, the value of Received-Amount should get subtracted from web-table calculated amount.

I have tried to read the checkbox in List (Web Element) but not able to calculate the sum of amount.

```
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tableParent\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span/input"));
    int rowsize=elements.size();
    int sum = 0;
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Boolean ischecked;
    for(int i=1; i< rowsize; i++){
        ischecked = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[i]//input")).isSelected();
        if(ischecked)
        {  
            WebElement tdtext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[i]//td[6])).getAttribute(\"value\")"));
            String str = tdtext.toString();
            values.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
            //values.add(Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[i]//td[6])).getText()"))));   
        }
    }

    for (int i: values) {
        sum += i;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
     String expectedVal = driver.findElement(By.id("AVC")).getAttribute("value");
     System.out.println("ExpectedVal: " + expectedVal);
```

Comment: Are you sure below is returning you the list of webelements. Looks like a single element to me.
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tableParent\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span/input"));

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect expression at the line:

```
ischecked = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[i]//input")).isSelected();

WebElement tdtext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[i]//td[6])).getAttribute(\"value\")"));
```

Change with:

```
ischecked = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[" +i +"]//input")).isSelected();

WebElement tdtext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[" +i +"]//td[6])).getAttribute(\"value\")"));
```

Comment: String tdtext =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[" +i+"]//td[6]")).getAttribute("value");
       String str = tdtext.toString();
       values.add(Integer.parseInt(str)); not able to get value

Comment: Try: `String tdtext =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[" +i+"]//td[6]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");` or `String tdtext =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[" +i+"]//td[6]")).getText();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57705383/store-unique-value-in-file-and-read-the-same-value-in-selenium-webdriver-java/57705657#57705657, Can u help me in this question also. @frianH

Comment: Sadly I don't understand your question the above link, please create new question with the specific you need, it seem like you need provide html code how the `id` you mean located in your web.

Comment: Can u please check now, is it clear in descriptions.

Comment: Yes I see you mean, but without html code I can't work, and sorry I say your question is too broad :)